# Unable to start OS after suspend

Tags: boot, suspend, asus, 19.10

```
uname -a
Linux n552vw 5.3.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 17:27:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Laptop: ASUS N552VW, latest bios.

### Problem

#### Reproduce:

1. Suspend the laptop (shuts down)
2. Open lid

Nothing happens. Light on the laptop glow, however no sounds anything happens. The screen is black - the keyboard, mouse is ignored.

The only solution is to hold power button and stop. Then the laptop start normally.

After start `journalctl` shows nothing - not a single error.

### Questions

1. Any clues what is going on?
2. Any way to log the problem?